# Cross comparing two lists within blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

within my controller, I obtain a list of roles with their associated permissions.  Additionally, I obtain a list of all permissions.

```
$roles = Role::with('perms')->get();
$permissions = Permission::all();
```

So now when I pass this to my view, I now have a list of roles with their permissions, and a list of all possible permissions.

Within my view, I am currently doing something like this

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $role->display_name or '' }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($role->perms as $permission)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                         {{ $permission->display_name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So I am essentially displaying all roles with their permissions.  Now, within each loop, I am trying to add something like the following

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <select name="add-permission-select" class="form-control"></select>
</li>
```

The above select should display all remaining permissions a role can have.  So I essentially need to see all the permissions a role has, and then cross check this against my $permissions list.  So lets say I have

```
PermissionA
PermissionB
PermissionC
```

And the first role only has PermissionA, the select options for this role should display PermissionB and PermissionC.

How would I go about cross comparing the two things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably making use of the collection filters.

Using the [Available Collection Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods), you could run `diff()`'s on each role/permission object filtering out what you do an don't need. See the [Diff](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-diff) and [DiffKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-diffkeys) methods.

Example:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$diff = $collection->diff([2, 4, 6, 8]);

$diff->all();

// [1, 3, 5]
```